# Insert variable within " " character string

Tags: r

Ok so I am writing this loop which I intend to loop through and paste the name from my vector into the loop. The intended destination for the paste of the variable name is to be within a URL link and also a destfile name between " " marks.

So far this is my procedure:

```
    # Download ETF AUM Files 
    file.list <- c("DDM","MVV","QLD","SAA","SSO","TQQQ","UDOW","UMDD","UPRO","URTY","UWM", "BIB", "FINU","LTL","ROM", "RXL", "SVXY","UBIO","UCC","UGE","UPW","URE","USD","UXI","UYG","UYM","DOG","DXD","MYY","MZZ","PSQ","QID","RWM","SBB","SDD","SDOW","SDS","SH","SPXU","SQQQ","SRTY","TWM","SMDD","UVXY","VIXM","VIXY")


    # Loop 
     for (f in 1:length(file.list)) {
        next.file <- file.list[i]
        file.name.variable <- paste(next.file[1])
        url <- "https://accounts.profunds.com/etfdata/ByFund/file.name.variable-historical_nav.csv"
        destfile <- "C:/R Projects/Data/etf_aum/file.name.variable.csv"
        download.file(url, destfile, mode="wb")
}
```

As you can see... I wish to enter the name of my variable inside the vector and paste into into my character strings for the url and destfile... Is there any way to do this?

Right now it wouldn't recognize that I wish the name to be a variable, as its already in " " marks it would take it as its written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is what you are after.

```
for (i in 1 : length(file.list)) {
  file.name.variable <-  file.list[i]

  url <- paste0("https://accounts.profunds.com/etfdata/ByFund/", 
                   file.name.variable, "-historical_nav.csv")

  destfile <- paste0("C:/R Projects/Data/etf_aum/",
                          file.name.variable, "csv")

  download.file(url, destfile, mode="wb")
}
```

Comment: Awesome! So all I needed was to ",file.name.variable," inserted unto my " " strings -fantastic - thank you, learn something new every day + the paste0 to remove my sep""

Comment: `paste` is vectorized.  So it would be more efficient to create the urls and destfiles outside the loop